# IEnumerator method compiles but no effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Jump` function which works:

```
void Jump() {
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 50, 0f);
}
```

I want to add a pause of 3 seconds within my function. I'm reading I should be able to do this with `WaitForSeconds` if I make the return type `IEnumerator`. Here is what I'm trying:

```
IEnumerator Jump() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 50, 0f);
}
```

Both versions compile fine but only the first version makes my object jump.

Why doesn't the `IEnumerator` version work?

Comment: are you calling the second version with StartCoroutine()?

Comment: For something like this, I would recommend using `Invoke("FunctionNameHere", 3); ` instead which will call the function after 3 seconds.

Comment: @ryeMoss for the second one I'm calling it inside `Update` if the user is pressing the up key.

Comment: @TimHunter I don't know if it'll work for me because this is a simplified version. In my actual code I have a `Grounded` variable that I set to false and then make true again after the 3 seconds. So that a user can only jump once every 3 seconds.

Comment: Oh, if you're going that route then I would recommend a straight forward setup that calls a function like this `void Jump(){ if(grounded){ rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 50, 0f); grounded = false; Invoke("Landed", 3);} }` with landed being something like `void Landed(){grounded = true;}`. Should work pretty straight forward to set grounded back to true 3 seconds after the previous Jump call.

Comment: Ideally though, you should have a box collider attached to the bottom of your character which toggles grounded as true/false if it's intersecting a "Ground" tagged object. But that can be tricky to get working right if not handled properly so something like the code I put above should work for a simple set up.

Comment: @TimHunter thank you, that code is working perfectly for me. Do you want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution to toggling a "grounded" boolean after a fixed amount of time would be to have the Jump function setup like so:

```
void Jump() { 
  if(grounded){ 
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 50, 0f); 
    grounded = false; 
    Invoke("Landed", 3);
  } 
}
```

Which can then be followed up by a Landed function to toggle it back to true after 3 seconds if setup like so:

```
void Landed() {
  grounded = true;
}
```